# Clone interface with some properties non-optional

Tags: typescript

An external library provides interface `Foo` with many optional properties:

```
interface Foo {
    propertyA?: string;
    propertyB?: string;
}
```

My code accepts a `Foo` and fills in some of the properties. Later code demands this partially-filled-in `Foo`.

```
interface FooWithA {
    propertyA: string;
    propertyB?: string;
}
```

What type annotation can I use to denote "this is a `Foo` with properties X, Y, Z non-optional", so that `strictNullChecks` stops complaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```
type FooWithA  = Foo & {
    propertyA: string;
}
```

Or you can extend the interface:

```
interface FooWithA extends Foo {
    propertyA: string
}
```

If all you worry about is the compiler complaining about null checks, you can use [`!` non-null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator) when using these properties.

Comment: Can I do this without hardcoding the property type for `propertyA`? Declare that `FooWithA.propertyA` has the same type as `Foo.propertyA`?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Look at [`! `non-null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator) which might solve your issue with `strictNullChecks`.